# dpkg: error processing package atom (--install) : couldn't install atom editor on Kubuntu 17.04 due to dependency problems

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

I'm trying to install atom editor on Kubuntu editor 17.04.
Below is the command execution and result.

```
 $ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/atom-amd64.deb 
 Selecting previously unselected package atom.
 (Reading database ... 172158 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack Downloads/atom-amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking atom (1.21.0) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on gconf2; however:
 Package gconf2 is not installed.
 atom depends on gvfs-bin; however:
 Package gvfs-bin is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package atom (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
atom
```

Eventhough the command execution failed, still still able to open atom editor and able edit files.

Below are the atom details installed in my machine.

```
$ atom --version
Atom    : 1.21.0
Electron: 1.6.9
Chrome  : 56.0.2924.87
Node    : 7.4.0
```

But how can I resolve this?

Comment: You can try `sudo apt install gconf2 gvfs-bin` then after installing, install atom.

Comment: I tried it. But didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

running the command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when installing on 18.04.
running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove` suggested to run the following:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

After which I ran `sudo apt-get install -f`
and finally `sudo dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb`.
This solved the issue for me!